# MS Access SQL to calculate the logarithmic average of dBµV

Tags: sql, ms-access, average, logarithm

Unfortunately my SQL skills are very basic. I hope someone can help me. I would like to calculate the logarithmic average over several dBµV values. Unfortunately I cannot use the standard average function as the result are not correct.

Today I have the data in Excel and my calculation works fine. Unfortunately, Excel is now reaching its performance limit and therefore I've imported the data into MS Access (I'm using MS Access Ver Office 365).

I have a table with an ID, frequency and the dBµV values. I would like to get the logarithmic average of all dBµV samples over a certain range of frequencies for a particular ID. The frequency starts at 122 and can go up to 1802. Not every ID has a value for all frequencies.

Frequency ranges can be as follows and never change (means the beginning and the end of the frequency range are constant):

- 122 to 170
- 178 to 226
- 234 to 530
- and so on

In Excel I used the following formula for the frequency range F122_170 (B1:H1 contains the dBµV values):

```
{=10*LOG(SUM(10^(B1:H1/10))/COUNTA(B1:H1))}
```

Now I am completely lost with the SQL statement to get the desired result.

Below is an example of my table "tblDev".

| ID | freq | dBuV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3977739907 | 122 | 32.44 |
| 3977739907 | 130 | 32.24 |
| 3977739907 | 138 | 31.93 |
| 3977739907 | 146 | 30.79 |
| 3977739907 | 154 | 31.31 |
| 3977739907 | 162 | 32.39 |
| 3977739907 | 170 | 32.43 |
| 3977739907 | 178 | 32.81 |
| 3977739907 | 186 | 32.21 |
| 3977739907 | 194 | 31.23 |
| … | … | … |

The output I would like to have is as follows:

| ID | F122_170 | F178_226 | F234_530 | F770_up |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3977739907 | 31.97 | 31.23 | 37.03 | 0.00 |
| 3845056609 | 32.24 | 23.40 | 41.09 | 38.18 |
| 3882949203 | 23.10 | 16.98 | 31.03 | 32.26 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Would be great if someone could help me with the SQL statement.

Best regards Patrik

Comment: This is not a software recommendation site, but there are many more powerful databases than MS Access if you are choosing a new database -- even free versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I once tried translating Excel formula to Access. Had to use VBA to build matrix multiplication procedure. I compared two methods in VBA with the Excel worksheet calc and got 3 different results. One method referenced Excel matrix functions in VBA and the other did not (this was code found on web). Never did get methods to agree.

Comment: The only value I can get agreement with is the 31.97. Did not provide enough data to get the desired output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm aware of way more professional db's than access. But all I have available on my company laptop, that can handle more data than Excel, is access. Since we are not allowed to install any other tools than what is provided, I have to deal with what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a *Log10* function:

```vb
Public Function Log10( _
    ByVal Value As Double) _
    As Double

' Returns Log 10 of Value.
' 2015-08-17. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

    Const Base10    As Double = 10

    ' No error handling as this should be handled
    ' outside this function.
    '
    ' Example:
    '
    '     If MyValue > 0 then
    '         LogMyValue = Log10(MyValue)
    '     Else
    '         ' Do something else ...
    '     End If
    
    Log10 = Log(Value) / Log(Base10)

End Function
```

Then you can run this query:

```sql
Select 
    ID, 
    Sum(AF122_170) As F122_170,
    Sum(AF178_226) As F178_226,
    Sum(AF234_530) As F234_530,
    Sum(AF770_up) As F770_up
From

    (Select 
        tblDev.ID, 
        IIf(freq Between 122 And 170, Log10(Avg(10 ^ (tblDev.dBuV / 10))) * 10, 0) As AF122_170,
        IIf(freq Between 178 And 226, Log10(Avg(10 ^ (tblDev.dBuV / 10))) * 10, 0) As AF178_226,
        IIf(freq Between 234 And 530, Log10(Avg(10 ^ (tblDev.dBuV / 10))) * 10, 0) As AF234_530,
        IIf(freq >= 770, Log10(Avg(10 ^ (tblDev.dBuV / 10))) * 10, 0) As AF770_up    From 
        tblDev
    Group By 
        ID,
        freq Between 122 And 170,
        freq Between 178 And 226,
        freq Between 234 And 530,
        freq >= 770) As T

Group By ID
```

Comment: Ups, I had the math reversed. Corrected. Now 31.97 is returned for the first group.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works just perfect. I've verified a few examples and so far all of them have exactly the same log average as with the formula in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

Query1: Log() returns natural log (base e) so to get log in base 10, divide Log(x) by Log(10)

```
SELECT tblDev.ID, 10*(Log(Avg(10^([dBuV]/10)))/Log(10)) AS dB, 
Switch([freq]<=170,"F122_170",[freq]<=226,"F178_226",[freq]<=530,"F234_530",True,"F770_up") AS Grp
FROM tblDev
GROUP BY tblDev.ID, Switch([freq]<=170,"F122_170",[freq]<=226,"F178_226",[freq]<=530,"F234_530",True,"F770_up");
```

Query2: to pivot results of query1

```
TRANSFORM First(dB)
SELECT Query1.ID
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.ID
PIVOT Query1.Grp IN (F122_170,F178_226,F234_530,F770_up);
```

Comment: @Jun7, thanks for your help as well. I tried your solution as well and it worked perfect too. All examples i verified were the same as in the excel.

Comment: Glad you have a working answer and accepted one. Can also upvote as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you can use:

```
select id,
       10 * log(avg(iif(freq between 122 and 170, 10^dBuV), null)) / log(10)
       10 * log(avg(iif(freq between 178 and 256, 10^dBuV), null)) / log(10)
from t
group by id;
```

Note:  This replaces the `SUM()`/`COUNT()` with `AVG()` . . . which I think is the same thing.

Comment: Tried and getting syntax error. Access has Log function but not Log10. Powers are accomplished with ^ symbol. Missing /10 in calc. Should not be a comma in front of FROM. Still get syntax error.

Comment: @June7 . . . I modified the answer.  I did pick up those functions from what looked like an MS Access documentation page.

Comment: They don't work in Access 2010 so maybe they were UDF or added in later Access.

Comment: @June7 . . . Like I said in a comment, there are more powerful databases that you could have chosen.

Comment: It's not for me to choose. I'll leave that to the OP.